# Start dbeaver from console

Tags: command-line

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` and I have installed `dbeaver`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:serge-rider/dbeaver-ce
sudo apt-get install dbeaver-ce
```

I have a `setupDevEnvironment`-script and I would like to launch dbeaver from the console, but haven`t found a way.

Any suggestions how to do this?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just typing dbeaver does not work, try:

```
dbeaver-ce &
```

with "&" to run in the background.

If I instead use just `dbeaver`, I get:

```
dbeaver: command not found
```

since I installed `dbeaver-ce`.

You should therefore call it like you installed it, always just check how the executable is really called.

###### Side-note (TL/DR):

You can find and add desktop launchers where all of the Linux desktop launchers are stored: in `/usr/share/applications` (you could also add new ones in `~/.local/share/applications`, but that should be empty and the default directory seems better).

It is a bit like getting the command that the start menu is using, only that it is not exactly this start menu icon (since dbeaver is not in `/usr/share/applications` in my case):

[image]

I do not know exactly how to do it, but adding dbeaver.desktop in that folder (and also to the defaults.list perhaps, but I do not know in which topic then!) might give you the chance to add executables as `dbeaver-ce` to an icon or file that you might be able to call from the command prompt, like a Desktop link would do.

This is untested, I vaguely remember it from another thing, therefore just a side-note.

Just check for example [Can't See Menus in Ubuntu 13.10](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1100&start=10) from the dbeaver forum or [Can't start Dbeaver by desktop icon](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/3971). Once you have a shortcut, you might also call it from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use dbeaver command from terminal or your script to launch its GUI.

```
$ dbeaver &
```

Comment: If you installed `dbeaver-ce`, like in the question, this does not work.